# Multiple eggs in pip's requirements file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, egg

**Question in short**

If I want to install `repo[tag_1]` and `repo[tag_2]` from two different dependencies, how can I tell pip such that it knows I want to install `repo[tag_1,tag_2]`?

**Question in detail**

I have a few homemade libraries that I want to import from a certain virtual environment. These libraries have dependencies, which are different for a local and a production environment. I am using eggs to make this distinction.

In the first library's `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    install_requires=[...]
    extras_require={
        'test': [...],
        'shared_2': [
            'shared_2 @ git+ssh://git@github.com/path_to_shared_2.git@master'
        ]
    }
)
```

In the second library's `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    install_requires=[...]
    extras_require={
        'test': [...],
    }
)
```

In the requirements file for the virtual environment:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/path_to_shared_1.git@master#egg=shared_1[test, shared_2]
git+ssh://git@github.com/path_to_shared_2.git@master#egg=shared_2[test]
```

If I try to install both these requirements, then due to the first line, we try install `path_to_shared_2.git@master#egg=shared_2` and due to the second line, we try to install `path_to_shared_2.git@master#egg=shared_2[test]`. Pip then quits with the error that it cannot resolve both.

Is there a way that I can specify that any egg for shared_2 is good enough, or even better, that I can specify multiple eggs, and that pip will just combine them, so if I want to install `repo[tag_1]` and `repo[tag_2]`, pip knows I need to install `repo[tag_1,tag_2]`?

**Error message**

On my local environment, pip is not complaining. On my colleague's local environment, he gets the following error message

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of shared-2 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of shared-2[test] to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install shared-2[test]==2.3.0 and shared-1[test,shared_2]==4.0.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    shared-2[test] 2.3.0 depends on shared-2 2.3.0 (from git+ssh://****@github.com/path_to_shared_2.git@master#egg=shared-2[test])
    shared-1[test,shared_2] 4.0.1 depends on shared-2 2.3.0 (from git+ssh://****@github.com/path_to_shared_2.git@master)

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '~/venv/test-sales-venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

** Solution **

It turned out that upgrading pip from version 21.1.1 to 21.3.1 solved the issue. Apparently there was a bug in an earlier version that got fixed now.

Comment: How would installing `repo[a,b]` be different from installing `repo[a],repo[b]`? Also, I'm surprised that pip reports this as a conflict. Extras are meant to be compatible with the "basic" version. Can you include the full error message that pip reports?

Comment: @a_guest: Thanks for your reply. I also don't know how they could be different. I have added the specific error message from pip to the question.

Comment: Perhaps try upgrading `pip` to the latest version. Otherwise, this looks like a bug in pip to me; basically the error message reads `shared-2 2.3.0` is incompatible with `shared-2 2.3.0` which doesn't make sense since it's the same thing.

Comment: What do you know, upgrading pip did the trick! Thanks for your support. :-)

Comment: It looks like [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10002) is the corresponding issue. It has been fixed in version [21.2](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id49).